# How to retrieve the greatest date interval of consecutive records that share the same status?

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.4.

Given a table with a timestamp and a boolean flag of read status:

```
CREATE TABLE status (
    id serial NOT NULL,
    created timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
    read boolean NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT status_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT status_unique_created_read UNIQUE(created, read)
);
```

I want to retrieve the greatest interval of consecutive records that share the same status. Each change of the `read` flag should start another group of records.

The final goal is to get the greatest interval of `created` dates that share the read status `True`.

As an example, let's populate the table with this records:

```
INSERT INTO status (created, read) VALUES ('2016-02-23 14:53:39.668225-03', true);
INSERT INTO status (created, read) VALUES ('2016-02-24 09:00:07.384002-03', true);
INSERT INTO status (created, read) VALUES ('2016-02-26 19:33:00.677397-03', true);
INSERT INTO status (created, read) VALUES ('2016-02-26 19:58:07.070881-03', true);
INSERT INTO status (created, read) VALUES ('2016-02-28 09:00:47.831193-03', true);
INSERT INTO status (created, read) VALUES ('2016-02-28 09:00:50.632217-03', true);
INSERT INTO status (created, read) VALUES ('2016-02-28 09:00:50.655375-03', true);
INSERT INTO status (created, read) VALUES ('2016-02-28 09:00:54.146508-03', true);
INSERT INTO status (created, read) VALUES ('2016-02-28 09:00:56.524389-03', true);
INSERT INTO status (created, read) VALUES ('2016-02-28 09:00:58.828541-03', true);
INSERT INTO status (created, read) VALUES ('2016-02-28 09:01:00.809748-03', true);
INSERT INTO status (created, read) VALUES ('2016-02-28 09:01:03.14392-03', true);
INSERT INTO status (created, read) VALUES ('2016-02-28 09:01:05.506604-03', true);
INSERT INTO status (created, read) VALUES ('2016-02-28 09:01:07.606256-03', true);
INSERT INTO status (created, read) VALUES ('2016-02-28 09:01:09.986617-03', true);
INSERT INTO status (created, read) VALUES ('2016-02-28 09:01:12.275312-03', true);
INSERT INTO status (created, read) VALUES ('2016-02-28 09:01:14.194565-03', true);
INSERT INTO status (created, read) VALUES ('2016-02-28 09:01:16.429208-03', true);
INSERT INTO status (created, read) VALUES ('2016-02-28 09:01:18.657266-03', true);
INSERT INTO status (created, read) VALUES ('2016-02-28 09:01:20.877406-03', true);
INSERT INTO status (created, read) VALUES ('2016-02-28 09:01:23.122152-03', true);
INSERT INTO status (created, read) VALUES ('2016-02-29 10:37:25.036703-03', true);
INSERT INTO status (created, read) VALUES ('2016-02-29 11:07:10.564814-03', true);
INSERT INTO status (created, read) VALUES ('2016-02-29 11:47:38.78204-03', false);
INSERT INTO status (created, read) VALUES ('2016-02-29 11:56:49.895785-03', true);
INSERT INTO status (created, read) VALUES ('2016-02-29 12:46:07.906734-03', false);
INSERT INTO status (created, read) VALUES ('2016-02-29 17:19:09.776746-03', true);
INSERT INTO status (created, read) VALUES ('2016-02-29 17:24:07.145661-03', false);
INSERT INTO status (created, read) VALUES ('2016-02-29 21:11:02.558749-03', true);
INSERT INTO status (created, read) VALUES ('2016-03-01 09:00:00.871397-03', true);
INSERT INTO status (created, read) VALUES ('2016-03-01 10:46:17.66168-03', true);
INSERT INTO status (created, read) VALUES ('2016-03-01 14:12:43.717506-03', true);
INSERT INTO status (created, read) VALUES ('2016-03-02 09:00:04.303278-03', true);
INSERT INTO status (created, read) VALUES ('2016-03-02 17:33:16.196374-03', true);
INSERT INTO status (created, read) VALUES ('2016-03-02 17:36:29.84208-03', true);
INSERT INTO status (created, read) VALUES ('2016-03-03 09:00:01.929879-03', true);
INSERT INTO status (created, read) VALUES ('2016-03-03 09:00:01.940345-03', true);
INSERT INTO status (created, read) VALUES ('2016-03-04 09:00:03.120712-03', true);
INSERT INTO status (created, read) VALUES ('2016-03-04 10:59:01.651798-03', true);
INSERT INTO status (created, read) VALUES ('2016-03-04 17:06:27.565846-03', true);
INSERT INTO status (created, read) VALUES ('2016-03-04 17:07:00.258593-03', true);
INSERT INTO status (created, read) VALUES ('2016-03-04 17:30:23.126116-03', true);
INSERT INTO status (created, read) VALUES ('2016-03-04 17:43:41.512822-03', true);
INSERT INTO status (created, read) VALUES ('2016-03-05 09:00:13.42016-03', true);
INSERT INTO status (created, read) VALUES ('2016-03-06 09:00:05.610203-03', true);
INSERT INTO status (created, read) VALUES ('2016-03-07 16:33:58.102805-03', false);
INSERT INTO status (created, read) VALUES ('2016-03-07 16:53:48.820488-03', false);
INSERT INTO status (created, read) VALUES ('2016-03-07 18:51:44.182288-03', false);
INSERT INTO status (created, read) VALUES ('2016-03-09 09:00:04.369842-03', true);
INSERT INTO status (created, read) VALUES ('2016-03-09 09:00:04.380432-03', true);
INSERT INTO status (created, read) VALUES ('2016-03-09 09:00:04.450373-03', true);
INSERT INTO status (created, read) VALUES ('2016-03-09 09:00:04.598239-03', true);
INSERT INTO status (created, read) VALUES ('2016-03-09 09:00:04.7075-03', true);
INSERT INTO status (created, read) VALUES ('2016-03-10 09:00:00.923048-03', true);
INSERT INTO status (created, read) VALUES ('2016-03-11 09:00:01.02605-03', true);
INSERT INTO status (created, read) VALUES ('2016-03-11 16:34:43.341189-03', true);
INSERT INTO status (created, read) VALUES ('2016-03-11 18:39:02.517519-03', true);
INSERT INTO status (created, read) VALUES ('2016-03-11 18:39:02.535953-03', true);
INSERT INTO status (created, read) VALUES ('2016-03-15 09:00:01.405166-03', true);
INSERT INTO status (created, read) VALUES ('2016-03-15 12:08:51.729326-03', true);
INSERT INTO status (created, read) VALUES ('2016-03-16 09:00:01.594785-03', true);
INSERT INTO status (created, read) VALUES ('2016-03-17 09:00:01.189489-03', true);
INSERT INTO status (created, read) VALUES ('2016-03-18 09:00:01.105867-03', true);
INSERT INTO status (created, read) VALUES ('2016-03-18 15:32:03.153641-03', false);
INSERT INTO status (created, read) VALUES ('2016-03-21 10:21:18.110903-03', false);
INSERT INTO status (created, read) VALUES ('2016-03-22 10:34:29.630107-03', false);
```

The grouped data might look like this:

```
min_created;max_created;read;count
"2016-02-23 14:53:39.668225-03";"2016-02-29 11:07:10.564814-03";TRUE;23
"2016-02-29 11:47:38.78204-03";"2016-02-29 11:47:38.78204-03";FALSE;1
"2016-02-29 11:56:49.895785-03";"2016-02-29 11:56:49.895785-03";TRUE;1
"2016-02-29 12:46:07.906734-03";"2016-02-29 12:46:07.906734-03";FALSE;1
"2016-02-29 17:19:09.776746-03";"2016-02-29 17:19:09.776746-03";TRUE;1
"2016-02-29 17:24:07.145661-03";"2016-02-29 17:24:07.145661-03";FALSE;1
"2016-02-29 21:11:02.558749-03";"2016-03-06 09:00:05.610203-03";TRUE;17
"2016-03-07 16:33:58.102805-03";"2016-03-07 18:51:44.182288-03";FALSE;3
"2016-03-09 09:00:04.369842-03";"2016-03-18 09:00:01.105867-03";TRUE;15
"2016-03-18 15:32:03.153641-03";"2016-03-22 10:34:29.630107-03";FALSE;3
```

And the answer to the `what's the greatest interval of dates between read status` should be:

```
"2016-03-09 09:00:04.369842-03";"2016-03-18 09:00:01.105867-03"
```

How to get this result using SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query will generate all the groups of intervals for each status.

```
select
    nn.created,
    (
        select
            (
                select
                    nn2.created
                from
                    status nn2
                where
                    nn2.created < nn1.created
                and
                    nn2.read = nn.read
                order by
                    1 desc
                limit 1
            )
        from
            status nn1
        where
            nn1.created > nn.created
        and
            nn1.read <> nn.read
        order by
            1
        limit 1
    ) as modified,
    nn.read
from
    status nn
order by
    nn.created
```

You can use it as a CTE (or a view) along with some SQL basic functions to aggregate the data to the group you want.

Eg.:

```
select 
    max(date_part('[year,month,day]',created) - date_part('[year,month,day]',modified))
from 
    [cte or view]
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll test your answer.

Answer (score 2):

here is another solution (works also on other db engines)

```
SELECT min(created), Max(created), read, Count(1)
FROM ( 
SELECT created, read
, (SELECT Max(created) FROM status  WHERE created < t.created AND  read <> t.read) x1
, (SELECT Min(created) FROM status  WHERE created > t.created AND  read <> t.read) x2
FROM status  t)
GROUP BY read, x1, x2
ORDER BY 1
```

Comment: Nice! It's even faster than the first answer. Thanks!

Comment: if you need improve speed of your query, you can add index on (created, read) to your table

Comment: Thanks! I've updated the question to include an id field and the indexes. I noticed that you used the `min(created)` and `max(created)` on the subqueries to identify the group. Replacing it by `min(id)` and `max(id)` works as well.